# Integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

For absolute convergence the integral is $\int_0^1 \frac{-\ln(\sin(x))}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Does this integral converges?

Comment: Do you want to evaluate the integral or do you want to just determine whether it converges? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @bjorn93 You are right, the intention was to determine convergence. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at $0$. Since $\sin(x) \sim x$ for small $x$ we expect that
$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\sqrt{x}} dx$
converges if
$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}} dx$
converges.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Since $\ln(\sin(x)) - \ln(x) = \ln(\sin(x)/x) \to \ln(1) = 0$
as $x \to 0$, there exists $\delta \in (0,1)$ such that 
$| \ln(\sin(x)) - \ln(x) | < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < x < \delta.$

Then,

1. $$\int_\delta^1 \frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\sqrt{x}} dx < \infty,$$
2. $$
   \int_\eta^\delta \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}} dx
   = [ 2\sqrt{x} \cdot \ln(x) ]_\eta^\delta - \int_\eta^\delta 2\sqrt{x} \cdot \frac{1}{x} dx
   = [ 2\sqrt{x} \cdot \ln(x) ]_\eta^\delta - [ 4\sqrt{x} ]_\eta^\delta \\
   \to 2\sqrt{\delta} \cdot \ln(\delta) - 4\sqrt{\delta}
   < \infty,
   $$
   as $\eta\to 0$,
   so
   $$\int_0^\delta \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}} dx < \infty,$$
   3.
   $$
   \left| \int_0^\delta \frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\sqrt{x}} dx - \int_0^\delta \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}} dx \right|
   \leq \int_0^\delta \frac{|\ln(\sin(x)) - \ln(x)|}{\sqrt{x}} dx
   \leq \int_0^\delta \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{x}} dx \\
   = \epsilon [2\sqrt{x}]_0^\delta
   = 2\sqrt{\delta}\epsilon
   < 2\epsilon
   < \infty
   .
   $$

Together these give
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\sqrt{x}} dx
< \infty.
$$

Comment: How can you formally show that $|\ln(\sin(x))| < |\ln(x)|$ for $x \in (0,1]$? Desmos shows this is not the case.

Comment: @Nix. Post rewritten.